# How to allow wget to overwrite files

Tags: linux, centos, command-line-interface, redhat, wget

Using `wget` command, how do I allow/instruct to overwrite my local file everytime, irrespective of how many times I invoke.

Let's say, I want to download a file from the location: http://server/folder/file1.html

Here, whenever I say `wget http://server/folder/file1.html`, I want this `file1.html` to be overwritten in my local system irrespective of the time it is changed, already downloaded, etc.  My intention/use case here is that when I call wget, I'm very sure that I want to replace/overwrite the existing file.

I've tried out the following options, but each option is intended/meant for some other purpose.

1. -nc =>  --no-clobber
2. -N => Turn on time-stamping
3. -r => Turn on recursive retrieving

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
wget -q http://www.whatever.com/filename.txt -O /path/filename.txt
```

-q is quiet mode so you can throw it in a cron without any output from the command

Comment: There is no direct option in `wget` command that does this without me specifying explicitly using `-O filename`?

Comment: It seems that there is no way to force overwriting every files when downloading files using wget. However, use -N option can surely force downloading and overwriting newer files.

wget -N 

Will overwrite original file if the size or timestamp change

Comment: Not true.  direct the output of the command into stdout and pipe it to the file: wget -q $urlYouNeedToGrap > $fileYouWantToOverwriteEverytime

Answer (score 8):

This option works

```
wget -N http://server/folder/file1.html
```

info

```
-N,  --timestamping            don't re-retrieve files unless newer than
                               local.
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `curl` instead?

```
curl http://server/folder/file1.html > file1.html
```

Comment: I'm not a Linux expert. What is the basic difference between `wget` and `curl`?  I'm sure that each command is meant for some specific purpose.

Comment: @Gnanam: They overlap a lot in basic CLI utility, actually.  Both can make an HTTP connection and save the result to disk.  For a run down on the differences check out http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html  Regardless, the above usage is complete valid.  There are other tools in this general area, too: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/comparison-table.html

Comment: Those 2 links are really helpful to understand the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it unless you also download the directories (so pass the -x flag). If you know what the file is, you can do use -O filename, so for example:
`wget http://yourdomain.com/index.html -O index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Untried: maybe you can work with `wget -r --level=0`.

Another possibility: `curl -O` overwrites (but it uses a different way of choosing the file name, which may or may not matter to you).

Comment: That `wget` line doesn't really do the correct thing because it creates a hierarchy of of subdirectories. `curl -O` on the other hand correctly downloads the file, overwriting existing copies.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put a small wrapper around the wget in your script?

The script could move all the files to a temporary location, then wget the remote files / web pages.

On success delete the files in the temporary location. On failure move the files back and raise an error.

There isn't a simple way to do what you want using just wget unless you know specifically the name of all files, in which case the -O option will allow you to force the filename of the file downloaded.